How do you calculate the centrifugal force generated by the bunches of protons inside the LHC?
I've determined that, during operation, the LHC accelerates 2808 bunches of protons with roughly 120 billion protons per bunch up to 99.9999991% the speed of light. I'd like to calculate how much total centrifugal force these protons generate per meter of the particle accelerator ring. (I recall hearing, long ago, during a tour of CERN that the bunches of protons in the beam have as much kinetic energy as a freight train). My first inclination was to calculate the mass of a proton traveling at this speed and then use mass x velocity^2 / r. However, I suspect that might be the wrong formula to use at relativistic speeds.
What is the right way to do this calculation?
Note: I read the answers to this question from 2012 but while the answers provided some equations, they did not define the variables used in those equations; therefore, those equations/answers do not answer my question.

This might help :  https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-physics/chapter/28-6-relativistic-energy/#:~:text=Relativistic%20kinetic%20energy%20is%20KE,reduces%20to%20classical%20kinetic%20energy.

I found some math on Wikipedia and worked out (if I did it right) that the force per meter is just under 3 N - which is amazing when you consider that the rest mass of all the protons in the entire particle stream is only 5 trillionths of a kg.

I think this question needs a little more love since there are two beam pipes in the LHC. There may be another factor of 2 that should be included.

I think you mean centrifugal force.  The centripetal force is provided by the magnets!

Yes, fixed, ...

The equation of motion of a particle with mass $m$ and charge $e$ moving in a pure magnetic field is given by $$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{m \vec{v}}{\sqrt{1-\vec{v}^2/c^2}} \tag{1} \label{1}= e \, \vec{v}\times \vec{B} .   $$ As the energy of the particle $$\mathcal{E}= \frac{m c^2}{\sqrt{1-\vec{v}^2/c^2}}$$ does not change with time because of $\vec{v} \cdot(\vec{v} \times \vec{B})=0$, eq. \eqref{1} simplifies to $$ \frac{\mathcal{E}}{c^2} \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}= e\, \vec{v} \times \vec{B}. \tag{2} \label{2}$$ Specializing further to the case where the particle is moving on a circle with radius $r$, eq. \eqref{2} becomes $$-\frac{\mathcal{E}}{c^2} \frac{\vec{v}^2}{r} \, \vec{e}_r = e \, \vec{v} \times \vec{B},\tag{3} \label{3}$$ with the unit vector $\vec{e}_r=\vec{r}/r$. Thus the magnitude of the force acting on the particle can be expressed in terms of its energy and the radius of the circle by the formula $$|\vec{F}|=\frac{\mathcal{E}}{r} \frac{\vec{v}^2}{c^2}, \tag{4}$$ simplifying further to $$ |\vec{F}|\simeq \frac{\mathcal{E}}{r} \tag{5}$$ in the ultrarelativistic limit $|\vec{v}|\to c$.
Inserting $r=4.25 \, {\rm km}$ for the radius of the LHC collider, $\mathcal{E} = 3 \, {\rm TeV}$ for the energy of a (single) proton and using the conversion factor ${\rm eV} = 1.6 \times 10^{-19} {\rm J}$, it is now a simple task to finish your exercise.

I used 7 TeV for the single proton energy from this post and did arrive at the same value of 2.97 N/m that I worked out using the math in the Wiki article. So it looks like the two different approaches do agree with one another.
